# Convert XML data to ER diagram

Tags: xml, erd

Is it possible to convert data in XML/TXT format into an ER Diagram? If yes, how?

I am looking at any open-source tool or code that would help in doing so using C# or VB

Comment: Yes. You will have to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is almost impossible because I don't know any good ER Diagram open source tool which would accept xml in entry and generate diagrams from it.

Answer (score 0):

yes it can be converted but using some techniques and some algorithms.
Pleas type convert xml to er diagram in google and click on the first link or yo can click on this given below.
ww1.ucmss.com/books/LFS/CSREA2006/SWW7234.pdf

here lies the solution,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will help. Upload the Xml to a SQL Server and use Visual studio to create a er diagram. It could be tables or stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using sql designer which is an ERD tool and it also provides a JS library to integrate it within your application.